# Unable to query External Object created from Files Connect for BOX

Tags: soql, lightning-connect, files-connect

I have setup files connect for Box.com in Salesforce. After adding external data source, it created a new external object but I am seeing this error when I try to view files in this object or run a query:
"EXTERNAL_OBJECT_UNSUPPORTED_EXCEPTION: "This query syntax is not supported by this external data source"

I have confirmed that permissions have been assigned properly, I am able to access files from Box via Files tab but this external object is not working.

Thanks